# Is synchronous (high performance) audio playback in Flutter possible/realistic?

Tags: android, flutter, audio, ffi, oboe

Similar question's [Using AssetManager class from Android NDK in a Flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62398886/using-assetmanager-class-from-android-ndk-in-a-flutter-app)

and
[Accessing assets from C++ plugin through Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62270389/accessing-assets-from-c-plugin-through-flutter)

have been asked and rather than asking for a technical answer I'm asking for guidance.

(Also this is my first ever question here so have mercy if I'm doing something wrong :))

Basically I need to be able to play multiple audio and video files perfectly in sync inside this app.  After a bit of research I got to learning android Oboe as this would solve all of my problems.  And it does... EXCEPT using FFI to communicate between Flutter and Oboe is a bitch and a half and ultimately leads to performance issues seeing how c->dart calls must be made on the main Dart thread.
So my question is...
Should I continue using Flutter and trying to make it work with a bunch of around the horn horseshit or should I just abandon Flutter and go native?
It seems to me that beyond my lack of knowledge there is currently a limitation of Flutter that requires me to go native for  what I want to do.
Is this true or not?
Can I achieve high performance audio inside a Flutter app or not?
Besides being possible is it actually a good idea to use Flutter for this or is it just going to make code maintenance a disaster?

Thanks!
Dano

Comment: i made a drum pad machine app which is very complicated has tons of features and its soon to be released. I have no performance problems but there are workarounds and it was super hard to build. I did lots of research to pull this off. Flutter is good enough to handle audio, i dunno video and pls no cursing words like "bitch", "horseshit"

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  That sounds very cool!  Glad to know that could be done.  I've migrated over to native dev and I really miss Flutter :(  Developer experience was top notch.  Out of curiosity if you were to do something like this again would it be faster to develop it for Android and IOS separately or use Flutter?  I personally found I was wasting more time with workarounds than just developing it twice.  Also, DM me when the app is out I'd love to give it a whirl!

Comment: no problems, im glad i could be of use!. My personal experience is, I used to develop android apps and it was just a suffering lol. Everything took a lot of time, even basic recyclerview. I learned flutter with this app and I have to say that flutter feels like an alien tech. It is so easy to understand, code, build useful features under 30 minutes! I will DM you the app when I release it. My app is currently finished only in Android because Oboe is android only. I can not say for IOS but I am 100% sure that I developed this app thanks to flutter and its fast easiness, flutter is the way imo!

Comment: Cs guy, did you finsh/release that app? If so, can you add a link here?